# co-ordinates on x axis are incorrect / auto-adjusted in QT Line Chart

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5.7

I am creating a simple line chart graph in QT 5.7.

Following is my certificate_page_childs table structure:

[image]

My c++ code :

```
QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
QString db_path = QDir::currentPath();
db_path =  db_path + QString("/some_file");
db.setDatabaseName(db_path);
db.open();
QSqlQuery query;
 query.prepare("SELECT hardness_val FROM certificate_page_childs where cp_id=:value");
 query.bindValue(0,statisticalanalysis::cert_id_gbl);
 if(query.exec()){
      int d = 1;
      while (query.next()) {
          series->append(d, query.value(0).toDouble()); //Method 1
          //qDebug() << query.value(0).toString();
          //*series << QPointF(d,query.value(0).toDouble()); // Method 2
          qDebug() << d;
          d++;

      }
 }
 else
 {
     qDebug() << query.lastError();
 }
 db.close();
 QChart *chart = new QChart();
 chart->legend()->hide();
 chart->addSeries(series);
 chart->createDefaultAxes();
 chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");
 chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::SeriesAnimations);
 ui->graphicsView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
 ui->graphicsView->setChart(chart);
```

Following is my output :

[image]

What i need :

[image]

X axis : No of readings

Y axis : Some value per reading

Please compare the x-axis with the output image and the desired one.

Can anyone guide me till desired results are achieved ?

Comment: Thanks @acraig5075 . Can you guide about correct indexing w.r.t x axis ?

Comment: Seems to me that the docs on point labels make it quite clear? [pointLabelsFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qxyseries.html#pointLabelsFormat-prop)

Comment: @acraig5075 please compare the x axis with the images i have provided. How can i achieve the desired results ? P.S : Its not about point labeling.

Comment: @eyllanesc check the output image, co-ordinates on x-axis are (1.0 ,2.3 ,3.5 ,4.8 , 6.0)  while the co-ordinates which i want are  (1,2,3,4,5,6) .

Comment: @eyllanesc My bad , im failing to make my question clear .  Please check my code, variable `d` is incremented by 1 in while loop . so my x should be (1,2,3,4,5,6)  while the output on x axis after running that code is (1.0 ,2.3 ,3.5 ,4.8 , 6.0) . How to fix this ?

Comment: @eyllanesc just vice the versa pal, my x is always an integer . Please see my code , variable d is incremented by 1 each time. But Qt line chart is forcefully converting it to decimals.

Comment: @Vikrant
in conclusion you want the values ​​shown on the X axis to be integers, am I right?

Comment: yes , and they should be plotted exactly below the y co-ordinate. (please see the image what i need)

Comment: @Vikrant try with my answer :)

Comment: @acraig5075 please remove the duplicate mark from this question as it was not about labeling but the conversion of x-axis co-ordinates from decimals to integers.

Comment: @Vikrant Certainly, done. But do you see how the two images that differ most obviously in the labels, make it seem that is your question? A good edit would be to replace your second image.

Comment: @acraig5075 Thanks. I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case as the X axis you have values ​​of `1:1:n` you can set a `tickCount` and the `labelFormat`:

```
QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->legend()->hide();
chart->addSeries(series);
chart->createDefaultAxes();
chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");
chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::SeriesAnimations);
ui->graphicsView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
ui->graphicsView->setChart(chart);
QValueAxis *axisX = static_cast<QValueAxis *>(chart->axisX(series)); // <--
axisX->setTickCount(series->count());  // <--
axisX->setLabelFormat("%d"); // <--
```

Comment: Perfect. This clearly shows my lack of research. Anyway thanks pal.

Comment: Ah... just a last question, Could this question be removed from duplicate category as it was nothing with the print labels ? is it possible ? [Sorry for that print label confusions]

Comment: @Vikrant the only one who can remove the duplicate is he who marked it